# Change lambda expression to a method - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
       foreach (var sr in searchResults.Select(
       result => new InterviewSearchResultUI
             {


             }
           )
        )
```

i need some extra logic inside the select method, so i need to change that lambda expression to a function where i can put more logic, something like :

```
       foreach (var sr in searchResults.Select(
       (result) 

           { 
             var a= a+1;
             new InterviewSearchResultUI
             {


             } 
           }
           )
        )
```

but i can not find the right way to do it, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close :)

```
foreach (var sr in searchResults.Select(
    result => { 
        var a= a+1; // note that this line doesn't actually make sense
        return new InterviewSearchResultUI
         {
             ...
         };
    }
    )) {

}
```

A multiline lambda:

- still needs `=>`
- has a `{}` after the `=>`
- needs a return statement

If you want to rewrite the lambda into a method instead, you can do this:

```
private static InterviewSearchResultsUI Transform(Result result) {
    var a= a+1;
    return new InterviewSearchResultUI
     {
         ...
     };
}
```

and then use it in the foreach like this:

```
foreach (var sr in searchResults.Select(Transform)) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that was what i needed it.